# How to convert varbinary to GUID in TSQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

how can I convert the HASHBYTES return value to a GUID?

This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login]
    @email nvarchar,
    @password varchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @passHashBinary varbinary; 
    DECLARE @newPassHashBinary varbinary;

    -- Create a unicode (utf-16) password
    Declare @unicodePassword nvarchar;
    Set @unicodePassword = CAST(@password as nvarchar); 

    SET @passHashBinary = HASHBYTES('md5', @password);
    SET @newPassHashBinary = HASHBYTES('md5', @unicodePassword);
```

Comment: Please salt passwords for taste! [Rainbow Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) Something simple: use the email - HASHBYTES(@email+'.'+@password)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply cast it:

```
select cast(hashbytes('md5','foo') as uniqueidentifier)
```

But there are two questions lingering:

- why cast HASHBYTES to guid? Why not use the appropriate type for storage, namely `BINARY(16)`
- I hope you are aware that MD5 hashing passwords is basically useless, right? Because of [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). You need to use a secure hashing scheme, like an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) or the [HA1 of Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).

Comment: Yes to both points. This is a legacy site I am working on for a company and those things were setup long ago, and changing them now is a lot of work.

Comment: Also, your code comment assumes that SQL Server Unicode type is `UTF-16`. This is incorrect. SQL Server Unicode types are encoded as `UCS-2`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179342.aspx

Comment: I have some SSAS cubes, and I needed a uniqueidentifier to put the cubes together but didn't have one in the database table I could use for the dimension that required it. Using this method allowed me to generate a uniqueidentifier from the string value, ensuring it was consistent whenever I needed to access it.